# Toggle between div tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 div tags and 1 button. I want to show the div tags one at a time example div1 is currently shown when the button is clicked div2 will show and div1 is hidden.
Here is my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">Hello</div>
<div id="2">Hi</div>
<div id="3">Bye</div>
<button>Change DIV</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentlyShown = 1;
    $('#changeButton').click(function () {
        if (currentlyShown < 3) {
            $('#' + currentlyShown).hide();
            currentlyShown++;
            $('#' + currentlyShown).show();
        } else {
            $('#' + currentlyShown).hide();
            currentlyShown = 1;
            $('#' + currentlyShown).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

**But**: Giving only numbers as IDs is not recommended! Furthermore you should use classes.

## A better way to realize what you want

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tqEN5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="yourClass">Hello</div>
<div class="yourClass">Hi</div>
<div class="yourClass">Bye</div>
<div class="yourClass">Dumb</div>
<button id="changeButton">Change DIV</button>
```

CSS:

```
.yourClass {
    display:none;
}
.yourClass:nth-child(1) { /*Change the number here to whatever div should be visible at the beginning*/
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentlyShown = 1; /*Change the number here to whatever div should be visible at the beginning*/
    $('#changeButton').click(function () {
        $('.yourClass').hide();
        (currentlyShown < $('.yourClass').length ?
             currentlyShown++ :
             currentlyShown = 1
        );
        $('.yourClass:nth-child('+currentlyShown+')').show();
    });
});
```

By doing so it is far more reusable + you can use more than 3 `<div>`s without changing the code.

Comment: @user3631478 could you please mark the answer as *the correct answer*, so other people can see that the question is answered? :-) glad I could help.

Comment: Oops sorry still new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the above example see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqwhe/6/).

```
$('button').on('click',function(){   
    //grab the currently active div
    var currentDiv = $('.active');    
    var currentId = parseInt(currentDiv.attr('id'));
    //hide it    
    currentDiv.removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');
    //get the id of the next div in the cycle
    var next = (currentId % $('div').length + 1);
    //show the next div
    $('#'+next).removeClass('hidden')
                .addClass('active');    
});
```

With the following CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div id="1">Hello</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none;">Hi</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none;">Bye</div>
<button>Change DIV</button>
</body>

$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("button").click(function(){
        count++;
        if (count % 3 == 0) {
            $("#1").css("display",true);
            $("#3").css("display","none");
        }
        if (count % 3 == 1) {
            $("#2").css("display",true);
            $("#1").css("display","none");
        }
        if (count % 3 == 2) {
            $("#3").css("display",true);
            $("#2").css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ysrotciv/Q7gh5/

Answer (score 0):

You can find working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLDvR/3/)

CSS

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="1" class="visible">Hello</div>
<div id="2" class="hidden">Hi</div>
<div id="3" class="hidden">Bye</div>
<button id="toggleButton">Change DIV</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shownId = parseInt($('.visible').attr('id'));
    $('#toggleButton').click(function () {
        $('#' + shownId).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
        shownId = shownId >= 3 ? 1 : ++shownId;
        $('#' + shownId).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
    });
});
```